# deseo setearle la fecha de una columna a otra columna que esta en distinta tabla en postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

quiero setearle los datos que son fechas de una columna FechaDesde de tabla X a una columna FechaDesde de tabla Y.

```
UPDATE Y SET FechaDesde = '2022-06-01 00:00:00';
```

Como hago pasarle la fecha de la columna FechaDesde que se encuentra en la tabla X a la columna de FechaDesde de la tabla Y?

Comment: Lectura sugerida para mejorar la pregunta: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 TL;DR: Edita la pregunta e incluye todo lo necesario para reproducir tu escenario, preguntas relacionadas con bases de datos, deben incluir los esquemas de las tablas, los campos con sus tipos de datos y demás detalles, del mismo modo, mostrar datos de prueba. Saludos.

Comment: Con qué criterio quieres asignar el valor del campo FechaDesde? Es decir, si hay N registros en la tabla X y M registros en la tabla Y, cómo decido a quién le cae el valor en Y.FechaDesde del registro 1, luego para el valor del registro 2... y así hasta el registro M? No es evidente cómo quieres asignarlo

Answer (score 0):

Algo así:

```
UPDATE Y
SET FechaDesde = X.FechaDesde 
FROM X
WHERE Y.sid = X.sid
```

En el WHERE del update debes colocar la condición que une a las tablas como si se tratara de un JOIN en un SELECT

```
SELECT *
FROM X
JOIN Y ON X.sid = Y.sid
```

Si no colocas la condición que une las filas, vas a actualizar la tabla X completa con un valor aleatorio de la tabla Y